# unit test for Angular service when service doesn't return an Observable?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, rxjs, karma-jasmine

I have looked at the [doc](https://angular.cn/guide/http#testing-http-requests) to learn how to test an http request, but I could not figure out how to unit test a service like below from the docs.

```
class service {

data$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<>(any);

getDatas(): Observable<any> {
    this.http.get(url).subscribe((response) => {
       this.data$.emit(response);
    });
    // if return a observable will be like:
    // return this.http.get(url).

  }

}
```

How can i test the service above if it's method doesn't return an Observable?

Comment: https://medium.com/netscape/testing-with-the-angular-httpclient-api-648203820712

Comment: Spy on `data$` and make sure `emit` is called.

Comment: Thanks, but the link you paste, it return an observable which is different from my question.

Answer (score 1):

The comment from The Head Rush is right.  Here is a code example I had handy for this.

service

```
export class SomeService {
  constructor() {}

  goDoSomething(): void {
      console.log('I did something');
  }

}
```

test

```
    describe('testing goDoSomething method', () => {
        it('should call console log', () => {
            spyOn(console, 'log'); // console is the object, and log is the method I expect to be called
            service.goDoSomething();
            expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
```